# 6 strange zero values when reading an image in a Byte()-Array with memorystream

Tags: vb.net

I converted a bitmap (6px, 3 in a row) to a Byte()-Array wit a memory stream.
When i display the values in a DataGridView thera are 6 strange zero values!

This image will describe what i mean!

[image]

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub CmdEinlesen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmdEinlesen.Click

        Dim Bild As Image = Image.FromFile("D:\PROGRAMMIERUNG\VISUAL_STUDIO\VISUAL_BASIC\DATA_GRID_VIEW\Dgv_Bmp_2DimArray\TestMap.bmp")

        Dim bitmapBytes As Byte()

        Using stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            Bild.Save(stream, Bild.RawFormat)
            bitmapBytes = stream.ToArray
        End Using

        Dim bytes2(250, 250) As Byte
        Dim zeilen As Integer = 0
        Dim spalten As Integer = 0
        Dim index As Integer = 54
        Dim triplet As String = Nothing

        For i As Integer = 54 To bitmapBytes.Length - 1
            DgvDaten.Rows.Add({bitmapBytes(i)})
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        For spalte As Integer = 0 To 23
            DgvDaten.Columns.Add("Spalte" & (spalte + 1), "Spalte" & (spalte + 1))
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What are you trying to extract from this Bitmap, setting a fixed position inside an array representing a Bitmap file? Use [Bitmap.LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits) to parse the Color values, if that's what you're after. BTW, the only fixed positions in a BMP format are between byte `0` and byte `21` (and this is just the base BMP format).

Comment: There are only 3 "strange" zeros.  Google "bitmap stride" to get ahead, a scanline in a bitmap is always a multiple of 4 bytes long.  Aligning the start of the line makes reading the bitmap efficient on a 32-bit processor.  3 pixels of 24bpp is 3 * 3 = 9 bytes, 3 extra padding bytes are necessary to make the stride 12.  The next 2 zeros belong to a red pixel, encoded as little-endian RGB, bb gg rr, so (0, 0, 255).